# Microphone & Headphones combo port does not work on Win 8 Bootcamp on MBP Retina 15"

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, headphones, windows

I have a macbook pro retina 15in and I have windows 8 installed via bootcamp.

I have bootcamp v5 drivers installed in windows 8 and everything works well except my external headset mic.  It is a Dr Dre Beats Solo with the mic integrated into the cable.  The mac os has no problem recognizing it and the fact that the audio jack has the mic on it as well.

Windows 8, no dice.  The headset works but the mic does not.

Do I need to download drivers to fix this issue?

Comment: Any solution on this issue? I have the same problem...

Comment: The only solution I have come across on the internet seems to be attaching a USB sound card.

Comment: same problem. any solution?

Comment: Same problem here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175045/21260