# Microphone / Headphones combo port does not work in BootCamp

Tags: audio, imac, bootcamp, microphone

I have an [iMac (27-inch, Late 2013)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP688) that has a [4-pole TRRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#TRRS_standards) headphone/headset combo port. 
On OS X any  headset works nicely (e.g. the Apple iPhone headset with microphone).

On Windows 7 64bit with BootCamp 5.1, 
the same headset on the same combo port does *not* work with the driver as delivered by Apple with BootCamp 5.1 (more precise: [5.1.5640](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721) ).
Apple phone support just told me it is not their problem, 
because it works on OS X.
So I tried installing a better driver on my own.

According to the Windows Device Manager, 
my sound card is a **Cirrus Logic CS4206B (AB 07)**. 
The closest match I could find on the Cirrus homepage was this one:
http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/cs4207.html
(Go to Resources -> Tools and Software).

The same page is also linked in [this related thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/35406/21260), 
including a step-by-step installation guide, 
but it doesn't work for me. 
Did someone get a 4-pole headset to work including the microphone on an iMac with the Cirrus Logic CS4206B (AB 07) sound card?

Comment: Search for CS4206B on Apple support homepage: https://discussions.apple.com/search.jspa?type=discussion&q=cs4206b

Comment: Asked the same question on discussions.apple.com: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6871937

Comment: Helpful thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6767136

Comment: Might be a problem with `HDAudio.sys` according to MS Troubleshooting Audio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj123860.aspx#jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6767136 this is currently not possible. If someone does get it to work I will happily award a bounty to an answer describing how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if people are still having a problem with this as it's been almost a year, but I was running into this problem with my Mac mini 2014 with Windows 10 Home and Bootcamp v6.0.
  The sound card is Cirrus Logic CS4208 (AB 108), and I couldn't get Windows to recognize the mic on my headset which was designed for iPhone/Apple usage.

After not being able to find the driver for the CS4208 (AB 108) at a legitimate site on the net (results almost always required a 3rd party driver downloader - no thanks!), I went to Cirrus Logic's website and tried to search for another driver.  I was able to find [CS4207](https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs4207/) from their website, downloaded the zip file, and tried to update the CS4208 driver with files on this zip.  The driver was taken, and, after a restart, the microphone now showed up (even though it was still showing CS4208 AB 108).  It works!

I even rolled back the driver and updated again to confirm it works, and it sure does!  I also have another 2016 MBP that I would like to test.  Will update here after.

Here's a few screenshots before the driver update to CS4207:
[image: Driver-Before][image: Recording-Before]

And after updating the drivers and restart:
[image: Driver-After][image: Recording-After]

Comment: MacBook Pro has no problem.  It has the Cirrus Logic CS8409 (AB 57) card, and when I looked in the Recording tab of the Sound Pref, it already had 'Internal Microphone' and 'Microphone'.  The 'Microphone' was showing as 'Not plugged in' and as soon as I plugged in my headset, it was working right away...

Comment: Great answer. Saved my days. Otherwise I would have to boot into Mac whenever I need to use the mic.

Comment: Thanks, this technique worked for my mac mini with the latest boot camp and windows 10.

Comment: Downloading and installing the CS2407 Drivers from Cirrus Webpage did it for me!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. It was a Windows privacy issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZssiZtyKaNk

You can test by recording your voice with the Voice Recorder Application. Give it permissions from Settings > Privacy Settings > Microphone. Also make sure Windows has permissions to use the microphone.

Comment: This is almost entirely irrelevant to the question. Changing privacy settings will not help if the driver doesn't allow for an external microphone to begin with.

Comment: Just left this answer here since I also thought my driver was faulty and it wasn't. I also reinstalled the windows driver and it still didn't work. I was trying everything and it turned out to be a privacy setting that didn't allow windows to use the microphone for any application including windows. I think it's at least worth a try, it worked for me on a macbook pro mid 2014

Comment: The privacy setting is also the only blocker to using my internal microphone CS4208 on MacBookAIr7,2 booting Windows 10 with UEFI.

Answer (score 2):

If people are still having this issue in 2019 and have USB-C ports on their Mac, Apple's USB-C to 3.5mm adapter seems to fix this issue. While it doesn't work on macOS, it certainly allow you to use the microphone on Apple Earpods (and the in-line controls) and other headsets. The adapter is $9 in US and is mainly for iPad Pro 2018. I hope this helps, as it works perfectly for me!

Or if you have an Xbox one controller with a 3.5mm jack (I'm not sure about ps4 controllers) you can use that as a USB sound card

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [Windows 10 running the latest Bootcamp does recognize the TRRS microphone now](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28726609#28726609):

> Hi there.  I've been monitoring and looking for a solution for this for sometime and it seems the latest version of bootcamp released today (Bootcamp 6.0) with Windows 10 fixes the problem.
>
> I had Windows 10 installed through bootcamp and updated to bootcamp 6 today (Aug 13).  Surprisingly, I plugged in my iPhone headset (which is TRRS) and noticed windows installing some drivers. ...
>
> Headset is working just like it does in OSX now, awesome for VOIP or gaming. Very happy camper here!
>
> Should note that I am running Windows 10 with Bootcamp 6 on a late 2013 Retina Macbook Pro.

Comment: Doesn't help those with older versions of Windows, though...

Comment: I have the latest Windows 10 Pro 64 bit and the latests Bootcamp (it just says Versio 6.0), but my headset does still not work. Is there anything else I would have to consder? Does it depend on the cable? The headset? The Mac?