# 2012 Macbook Pro Bootcamp Driver For External Mic

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, audio, headphones, microphone

I'm still having the same issue discussed at length in the below thread to this date and can't find a solution that works for me:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6767136
[Microphone / Headphones combo port does not work in BootCamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175045/microphone-headphones-combo-port-does-not-work-in-bootcamp)

I have an old 2012 Macbook pro running Windows 10 and trying to utilize a gaming headset that has combined headphone/microphone. The headset has a mic cord and a headphone cord, so utilizing a mic/headphone to TRSS adapter as seen here:
https://cdn3.volusion.com/zcgcs.pctzl/v/vspfiles/photos/29-8327-2.jpg?v-cache=1593342269

The headphones work totally fine, but can't get the microphone to be recognized in Windows 10 and can't find a driver to fix the issue. Separately, I've confirmed the headset/adapter works totally fine from a hardware perspective and is recognized on the MacOS side of the computer.

This is what my audio devices look like in device manager:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is no driver for a mic or headphone connected to a 3.5" audio jack. The device driver is for the audio system that the jack is connected to, not the jack itself.  This applies to all computers and operating systems, not just Macs

As you can see from the device tree image you posted, the microphone is recognized as an input device and is technically working properly.  However...

**You have the wrong TRRS adapter**

[There are two different TRRS adapters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239564/119271), one for Apple and another for Android (everything else). The difference is the ground and microphone connectors are reversed.  The microphone is  "seen" because the audio chip senses the resistance and continuity of the completed circuit but it won't work because it's backward.

You need to get a microphone/headphone adapter that is Apple compatible. You can also use a [USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271) with dedicated mic and headphone connectors for better sound and reliability.